# Reading and printing same xml element tag android

Tags: android, android-xml

I want to print every VERS for each CHAPTER from the xml below. My problem is that when i print the item only the first element of vers is printed per chapter. Then the same element loops x number of times depending on number of vers.

Comment: scroll the question the code is below, am trying to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `VERS = parser.getValue(e, "VERS");` gives you always the first VERS in a CHAPTER back. Instead you must loop over all VERS - which is the `NodeList` of `nodeChapterList` in your case.

Example:

Replace `VERS = parser.getValue(e, "VERS");`

with `VERS = parser.getValue((Element) nodeChapterList.item(chap), "VERS");`

EDIT: I checked your code again and changed what was necessary to get it working.

```
    public final void test(Context context) {
    try {
        InputStream getXML = context.getResources().getAssets().open("bible.xml");

        DocumentBuilder parser = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = parser.parse(getXML);
        NodeList verses = document.getElementsByTagName("VERS");

        for (int i = 0; i < verses.getLength(); i++) {
            Node vers = verses.item(i);
            String chapter_number = vers.getParentNode().getAttributes().getNamedItem("cnumber").getNodeValue();
            String vers_text = vers.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
            String vers_number = vers.getAttributes().getNamedItem("vnumber").getNodeValue();

            Log.d("STACKOVERFLOW", "vers: " + chapter_number + ", " + vers_number + " >" + vers_text + "<");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FactoryConfigurationError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With your text from the bible put in a file in `asset/bible.xml` (btw. I'm glad you stopped copying the bible after the first 7 days :-) I get this output:

```
08-24 22:35:35.463: D/STACKOVERFLOW(17950): vers: 1, 1 >Au commencement, Dieu créa les cieux et la terre.<true, 1
08-24 22:35:35.463: D/STACKOVERFLOW(17950): vers: 1, 2 >La terre était informe et vide: il y avait des ténèbres à la surface de l'abîme, et l'esprit de Dieu se mouvait au-dessus des eaux.<true, 1
08-24 22:35:35.473: D/STACKOVERFLOW(17950): vers: 1, 3 >Dieu dit: Que la lumière soit! Et la lumière fut.<true, 1
....
```

Explanation of DOM and the code:

- I start directly with the list of verses. To get the chapter I just go up to the parent (which is the chapter) and get its attributes.
- DOM's elements (like `<VERS/>`) treat the CDATA in it like an extra child node. Thats why I do an extra `getChildNodes()` on each `vers`.

Comment: can you provide me with an example

Comment: Another line is: `NodeList nodeChapterList = document.getElementsByTagName("VERS");` which should be `NodeList nodeChapterList = e.getElementsByTagName("VERS");` as the VERS elements are in/below CHAPTER elements.

Comment: VERS is still null after last change

Comment: @Nikita is it working now? If so, please mark the correct answer.

Comment: ok i found another way but i will mark you best. Thanks for your help :)